# Increase frame rate of webcams

Tags: multithreading, opencv, webcam, frame-rate, beagleboard

I have two webcam (Logitech C310) connected to beagleboard-xm (Angstrom). I am capturing video from both the webcam and displaying it on two separate widow using OpenCV. I am using two threads (one for each webcam ) to capture and display video from webcams.

The problem is:

1. Frame rate that I am getting from both cameras is very low (around 3 fps with resolution 640 X 480)
2. While running the code sometimes it works fine but sometimes gives the following error :

   Gtk:ERROR:gtkaccelmap.c:113:_gtk_accel_map_init: assertion failed: (accel_entry_ht == NULL)
   Aborted

Comment: what language do you use..? I used javacv and use 3 cameras (Lifecam), indeed it's slow (and I didn't check how many fps I got), but I am sure you can get more than 3 fps for just 2 cameras..
and maybe you want to connect 1 camera to 1 exclusive usb root connection.. in my case, when I connect 3 of them using the same usb root, the program cannot run..

Comment: I am using OpenCV with C interface. When I connect only one webcam frame rate is around 6 fps.

Comment: maybe you already see this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039575/how-to-set-camera-fps-in-opencv-cv-cap-prop-fps-is-a-fake
you may try to give openCV a suggestion about the fps by setting it..
but the bigger role is played by your hardware itself.. I never use logitech before.. sometimes openCV's implementation for some camera types is still not perfect.. and yes, it also depends on your beagleboard condition; which bridge your usb cam connection with the pc I suppose..